# Mono - The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, compilation, mono

I'm trying to compile my c# project on my raspbian raspberry pi using mono. This is the command I'm using to compile it:

```
csc -r:./bin/Release/PublishOutput/Discord.Net.Core.dll -r:./bin/Release/PublishOutput/Discord.Net.Commands.dll -r:./bin/Release/PublishOutput/Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll -r:./bin/Release/PublishOutput/RedditSharp.dll */*.cs
```

But I get this error every time:

```
error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I've tried adding `-r:System.Runtime.dll`, but I get this error:

```
error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll' could not be found
```

How can I reference System.Runtime so that I can compile my project?

Comment: Has Mono renamed its C# compiler? It always used to be `mcs`, not `csc`. Are you *building* on Raspbian with Mono, or doing that on your desktop?

Comment: Just compiling. Both `mcs` and `csc` give the same error. I don't know that the difference is. In mono's tutorial on http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/ they use `csc` though.

Comment: Interesting. It's possible that I'm way out of date on Mono :) One alternative option to consider is looking into using the .NET Core SDK - I believe that can now be done on Raspberry Pi, although possibly using a preview release. (Don't get me wrong, it should be doable with Mono, but I'd use .NET Core if possible ;)

Comment: I tried using .NET Core. I don't think it supports asyncronous tasks and threading though.

Comment: It absolutely does :)

Comment: When I try to publish it as linux-64, I get this error:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kTNJAKLW

Comment: I suggest you ask a *new* question about that - but bear in mind that a Raspberry Pi isn't x64, which may well be what's wrong. I would *start* by just making sure that `dotnet run` works, and work out publishing separately.

Comment: That's the main reason I was trying to use mono instead, as I don't think .NET Core explicitly supports 32-bit.

Comment: These are instructions for running previously-published code on the Raspberry pi: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md - but yes, it sounds like the SDK itself still won't run on the Pi :(

Comment: .net Core does support ARM32, and specifically targeting Raspberry Pi: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/29